# Cloud datalab fails to deploy with ERROR: Could not pick a region and/or zone

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datalab

When I try and deploy Datalab I'm seeing the following error in the logs during the deploy of the datalab appengine module:

```
Apr  9 21:14:42 datalab-deploy-main-20160409-21-12-10 startupscript: ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Could not pick a region and/or zone.
Apr  9 21:14:42 datalab-deploy-main-20160409-21-12-10 startupscript: Step deploy datalab module failed.
```

I'm seeing a module called datalab show up (says it's in us-central) but when I go back to the page to launch it, it asks me to Deploy again. I've retried 3-4 times with the same result.

Nothing else is the logs sticks out as an error or issue. Any suggestions to help get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the cloud project I was trying to start datalab on was missing a service account necessary for datalab to run successfully. I won't post it here because they are specific to each cloud project.